# how to check Codenvy username

Tags: command-line-interface, codenvy

I am trying to connect using [Codenvy cli](http://docs.codenvy.com/cli/) to my Codenvy workspace

Now I just don't know my username and password, as I used GitHub to login.

https://codenvy.com/dashboard/#/account/profile page does not list username.

I also checked support knowledge based at https://codenvy.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/all

How to check codenvy username ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your username is the email address

In order to get your password, for now, you have to require a password change
https://codenvy.com/site/recover-password

You'll receive a mail and then you'll be able to set your password

Then this email/password will be used as credentials

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can run a call against the API test harness (for the user) at http://docs.codenvy.com/api/

[image: pic] - page shown below.